# Is the complement of a bounded set bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ a metric space and $B_X$ the closed unit ball in $X$. It is possible to proof that $X\setminus B_X$ is not bounded (i.e. the diameter of the set is finite, $$\operatorname{diam}(K)=\sup\{d(x,y)\mid x\in K, y\in K\},$$ where $K\subseteq X$) using the fapt that is the complement of a bounded set?

In $\Bbb{R}^2$, with euclidean distance, it seems to be valid this argument. Or not?

Is there somewhere, maybe a General Topology book, results concerning the bounded set and their properties in metric space?

Comment: It might or might not be bounded. In $\mathbb{R}^2$, it's true. In $[0,1]$, it's not.

Comment: To prove it for $\mathbb{R}^2$, try a proof by contradiction. If a set and its complement were both bounded, then all of $\mathbb{R}^2$ would be bounded. But this is obviously a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

This result holds:

> $X \setminus B_X$ is bounded if and only if $X$ is bounded.

Proof:

$B_X$ is certainly bounded, with $\operatorname{diam}(B_X) \le 2$.

If $X \setminus B_X$ is bounded then $$X = B_X \cup X \setminus B_X  $$

and is hence bounded as a union of two bounded sets. Namely: $$\operatorname{diam}(X) \le \underbrace{\operatorname{diam}(B_X)}_{\le 2} + \underbrace{d(B_X, X \setminus B_X)}_{<+\infty} + \underbrace{\operatorname{diam} (X \setminus B_X)}_{<+\infty} < +\infty$$

Conversely, if $X \setminus B_X$ is unbounded, then so is $X$ since $$+\infty = \operatorname{diam}(X \setminus B_X) \le \operatorname{diam}(X)$$

which implies $\operatorname{diam}(X) = +\infty$.